# Why is my loop running only once in a Google Sheet with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am unable to figure out on why my loop is running only once.
I am sitting here for like 2 hours to figure it out, but no luck.
please help

```
var tempSheetValues1 = currentSheet.getRange("B2:B" + lastRow).getValues();

// considering length to be 5
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var id = tempSheetValues1.slice(i, i + 1).join('');

  var url = 'https://api.demo.hitmebro/' + id + '?language=en';
  Logger.log(url);

  // Check if the test id exists
  var response = hitApi(url, "get", null, headers, "inputId");
  Logger.log(response);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var Collection = data.data.inside;
  var rows = [];
  data;

  for (i = 0; i < Collection.length; i++) {
    data = Collection[i];
    var more = rows.push([data.xid]);
  }

  dataRange = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, 1);
  dataRange.setValues(rows);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `var i` inside inner and outer loop. Your inner loop changes `i` and it terminates outer loop

Comment: @Justinas My bad, I did not check that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preamble**

Since comments to the question deal with the issue, I added several optimization points to consider, paying attention to them will benefit you in the long run.

**Suggestions**

1. Move to the new V8 runtime to make use of the latest ES6 features and syntax:
2. Make use of built-in `Array` methods, like `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, etc. - it improves readability, reduces probability of bugs creeping in (because you forgot to change `i` to `j` - exactly your case).
3. Use destructuring assignment - again, it improves readability and, especially if combined with TypeScript (or JSDoc) is a joy to use (+improved type safety).
4. Use `const` as much as you can (unless you *really* need to reassign - and use `let` then, not `var`), most certainly never use *undeclared* variables (I assume `dataRange` is defined somewhere prior to the code sample, but just in case...).
5. **[edit]** it might sound counter-intuitive, but variables aren't meant to be *rewritten*, the name refers to the fact that they can hold *any* value. Thus, please, avoid resetting (like `let data = 'some_val'; data; data = 'new_val'`) - it leads to messy and / or buggy code. Instead, decalre a new one or try to avoid it at all (see below).

**Optimized code**

This is not the most optimal version there is, but is definitely a start (e.g., you can take the `getRange()` out of the loop to improve execution speed on large collections drastically, issue concurrent requests to the API with `Promise.all()` - thank V8 - etc.)

```
const tempSheetValues1 = currentSheet.getRange("B2:B" + lastRow).getValues();

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const id = tempSheetValues1.slice(i, i + 1).join('');

  const url = `https://api.demo.hitmebro/${id}?language=en`;
  Logger.log(url);

  // Check if the test id exists
  const response = hitApi(url, "get", null, headers, "inputId");
  Logger.log(response);

  const json = response.getContentText();

  const parsed = JSON.parse(json);

  const { data } = parsed;

  const { inside } = data;

  const rows = inside.map(elem => [elem.xid]);

  const dataRange = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, 1);
  dataRange.setValues(rows);
}
```

**Notes**

1. Hopefully I didn't miss anything when rewriting the inner loop logic, feel free to correct me if something's wrong.

**References**

1. Variable declaration [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)
2. `Array` built-in methods [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#) on MDN
3. Migrating to V8 runtime [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration)
4. Destructuring assignment [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on MDN